# Get PHP script result from a page with HTML content by AJAX

Tags: php, ajax

I have a PHP page with HTML content in it. Now I run some PHP codes between HTMLs and I get some results. The fact is, when I try to get a respond from this page by AJAX it'll show me the whole page content and plus the result I was looking for. What can I do to prevent the page from writing extra content. I know whenever something get printed on page it'll go as respond to the AJAX call but I want a way to somehow fix this.

My page file (name: page.php):

```
<?php echo $Content->GetData('HEADER'); ?>
    <div id="Content">
      <div id="Page">
        <?php if($Content->GetData('PAGE','IS_TRUE')) : ?>
        <?php if(NULL !== $Content->GetData('PAGE','TITLE')) : ?>
        <?php echo $Content->GetPlugins("Page:" . $Content->GetData('PAGE','ID') . ",BeforeTitle"); ?>
        <div id="Title" dir="rtl">
          <a href="<?php echo $Content->GetInfo('ABS_ROOT') . "page/" . $Content->GetData('PAGE','NAME'); ?>"><?php echo $Content->GetData('PAGE','TITLE'); ?></a>
        </div>
        <?php echo $Content->GetPlugins("Page:" . $Content->GetData('PAGE','ID') . ",AfterTitle"); ?>
        <?php endif; ?>
        <div id="Content" dir="rtl">
          <div style="float: right; width: 966px; padding: 6px">
            <?php echo $Content->GetPlugins("Page:" . $Content->GetData('PAGE','ID') . ",BeforeContent"); ?>
            <?php echo $Content->GetData('PAGE','CONTENT'); ?>
            <?php echo $Content->GetPlugins("Page:" . $Content->GetData('PAGE','ID') . ",AfterContent"); ?>
          </div>
        </div>
        <?php else : ?>
        <div id="Content" dir="rtl">
          <div style="float: right; width: 966px; padding: 6px">
             There is no page like this in our archives.
          </div>
        </div>
        <?php endif; ?>
      </div>
    </div>
<?php echo $Content->GetData('FOOTER'); ?>
```

If I write an address in my browser like this `localhost/cload/blog?action=rate` it'll go through my redirection list and show the page.php with `blog` plugin loaded. The problem is I want to call my `blog` plugin by AJAX through this address but it will first render the page data.

Sorry if this is messy.

Comment: I'm afraid you need to clarify your question a bit. What is returned now and what is supposed (or you want) to be returned instead?

Comment: maybe use `die();` where you want your code to stop executing?

Comment: Or don't output the parts you don't want passing to AJAX?

Comment: @ArashShahkar, I don't know how to clarify it I'm sorry!. webbandit, I think you didn't get my point. andrewsi, Yes you're right but I can't put condition for every extra stuff in my page.

Comment: @MahanGM - then why not create a second version of the page to be called via AJAX?

Comment: @andrewsi, I think my implementation of the system is somehow wrong and I can't do such a thing like this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd suggest modifying `page.php` to be some functions, primarily a data processing function, and then an output function.  Then, when you load the page, put a [check in for whether it's an AJAX request](http://davidwalsh.name/detect-ajax), and if so, echo the data you want as JSON, otherwise render the page using the output function.

Alternatively, you could create a second, separate page, but that could be more difficult to maintain than a single file.

Comment: Thanks, seems to be handy. I'll try it.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you should check whether your request is a ajax request, if it is so you should change your response to return only the result whatever  want.

This php code will give an rough idea on this.

```
if($request->isXmlHttpRequest()){
  return new Response(json_encode($data_array));
}
```

Hope this will help.

Comment: I did what @ernie suggested. Thanks.